# Background Image gets displayed multiple times

Tags: html, css, background

I have built a simple Website with a background. When I open it on my laptop the background its prefectly fine but when I use a phone or a bigger monitor the background is displayed multiple times. How can I display it only once.

My css Code for the background is:

```
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Comment: Hi! could you please share link ?

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think there is missing width property, So can you check by adding width

width:100%

Comment: didnt work unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you should hide your overflow.

here is a working [example](https://nexuscode.online/editor/wZkfULtXCQ) check it out.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. 
Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. [link-only-answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info)